# What do you call a black person from South America?

Tags: vocabulary

People in the US call black people "African-American". So, what do you call black people from South America, or Australia?

Comment: Are you talking about people from these continents/countries who are now resident in the US or who remain resident in their own continents/countries?

Comment: Regardless of the answer, in English it is never "**how** do you call", but "**what** do you call".

Comment: @KillingTime No idea, I keep hearing on TV "african american" instead of "black", and was wondering do you call "african american" every black person, even if it is not from africa.

Comment: How about "human"?

Comment: Please don't write answers in comments; they are harmful to our site. Doing
so bypasses our community-moderated quality measures by not permitting
community editing or paired up- and down-voting available on comments, as
well as having [other problems detailed on
meta](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1644/3171). Comments 
are for clarifying and improving the question; please don't use them for
other purposes.

Comment: @Peter Mortensen: By “copy editing” this question after it was closed, you pushed it into the Reopen Review Queue — and now it’s [been pushed out](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/379896), before the OP has had a chance to see that it was closed. Please don’t make cosmetic changes to a recently closed question unless you are fixing the reason why it was closed.

Answer (score 1):

> So, what do you call black people from South America, or Australia?

I can't speak for South Americans, but Australians typically call them "people". Where relevant, we might specify broad ethnicity (Indian, African, Chinese, Aboriginal, etc), but it's more common to just use their names (Bob, Ghandi, etc).

Comment: It is common for Australians to extend this courtesy to fair-skinned and mid-toned people as well. :)

Comment: So, for example, you would never refer to a person as ***a blonde*** or ***a brunette**?*  ***A barber*** or ***a doctor**?*  ***A friend*** or ***an enemy**?*  ***A man*** or ***a woman**?*  Your “answer” seems to be just a comment on political correctness, and [Hot Licks already covered that](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/544566/26083#comment1338030_544566).  If Australian English really doesn’t have a word for ***a black person**,* at least say that explicitly.

Comment: @Scott The categories you mention *are* used in Australia: hair colour, profession, gender, and even friendship. Skin colour is something we recognise; it’s just not widely used in conversation, other than the adjectives “fair-skinned” or “dark-skinned” in broadcast and official reporting. As for comments and answers, Stack Exchange considers them separate categories, with comments fair game to be promoted to answers by anyone. Nevertheless, Hot Licks commented from a non-Australian context whereas I answered from an Australian context. Feel free to bring this up on Meta.ELU.

Comment: Funny you should mention the non-equivalence of comments and answers, because (as I said) I believe that your answer would be better suited as a comment, *and your comment (above) contains information that belongs in an answer.*